# Spring boot multiple datasource to call same service without @Qualifier

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement where we will be using multiple darasources to call same dao method. The databse schema is all same.
Currently we are using datasource properties in application.properties and using below code to get datasource and call respective dao method with that.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource ds;

ds.getAllUsers(){....};
```

Now I will have multiple beans like below:

```
@Bean(name="comp1")
@ConfigurationProperties("ds.comp1")
public DataSource comp1DataSource(){
return new DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I can use @Qualifer to point to respective datasource bean, but I want to call same method getAllUsers with all datasource beans. So I was thinking to have all datasource in a list and then iterate it with to call the method.
Please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can inject automatically all beans with the same type using an array or list with @Autowired (by field or constructor). The implementation/configuration will dependent on how you are using the datasource (Spring Data Repository, JdbcTemplate or others).